# sqlalchemy, bidirectional many to many with association object, parent and child classes

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

In the documentation for sqlalchemy bidirectional many to many with association object

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")
```

The names of the tables are `parent` and `child`.

In this orm scenario, does sqlalchemy still treat these tables as parent to child in the rdbms sense? Or is this portion of the documentation just holding over the names of the classes, `Parent` and `Child`, from above on the page? The code seems to create a symmetrical relationship.